# Why setting some attributes of a class is not possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes, python-requests

I tried to create my own dummy response inherited from `requests.Response`. It would add an extra attribute and overwrite an existing one:

```
import requests

class MyResponse(requests.Response):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hello = "world"
        self.ok = False

print(vars(MyResponse()))
```

Adding `self.hello` is fine, but when I want to force `self.ok` to a value I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yop/.PyCharm2019.2/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(vars(MyResponse()))
  File "C:/Users/yop/.PyCharm2019.2/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.ok = False
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

**Why are there some attributes which cannot be set/overwritten?**

Comment: Did you think about implementing a setter?

Comment: I could be wrong, but as .hello isn't an attribute of the parent, and .ok is, you can't overwrite it.

Comment: @JammyDodger It's not the mere fact that `ok` is inherited that prevents assigning to it directly, but how the parent defines it (as a property with no setter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ok` is a [property](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#property) of `requests.Response` but it [has no setter](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/models/#Response) so it can't be set.

Instead, you can override it and always return `False` (or `True` or whatever you want):

```
class MyResponse(requests.Response):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hello = "world"

    @property
    def ok(self):
        return False
```

Alternatively, look at a proper mocking solution such as the [`mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) module.